# Highcharts Export Pie Chart to PDF offline not display properly

Tags: javascript, pdf, charts, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for my project (localhost) and I want to export my charts (Pie chart & Bar chart) to PDF **offline**.

As the given [highcharts image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shWSs.png), the bar chart looked good but the pie chart was not displaying properly. I have tried to export SVG & PNG, both works fine, only PDF gets me into trouble.

Any idea on how should I fix this issue? Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/3d406av3/20/

```
$(function () {
   Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {marginLeft: 400},
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Chart',
            x: 50,
            y: 130,
            margin: 150
        }, plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            var val = this.y;
                            if (val < 1) {
                                return '';
                            }
                            return val;
                        },
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
        }, xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                style: {
                    left: '50px',
                    top: '18px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'John',
            data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6], 
            center: [0, 100],
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Total',
            data: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                y: 13,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                y: 23,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
            }],
            center: [-250, 250],
            size: 150,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }]
    }, function (chart) {
        chart.renderer.text('Pie Chart', 120, 320)
            .css({
                color: '#4572A7',
                fontSize: '16px'
            })
            .add();
    });
});
```

Comment: Refer this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

Comment: See this is from yours http://jsfiddle.net/userasr/zzh1xd2b/

Comment: @ASR I want to export PDF when there is no internet connection. The jsfiddle you provided unable to export PDF offline.

Comment: This one works now http://jsfiddle.net/userasr/zzh1xd2b/1/

Comment: @ASR I have tried your jsfiddle to export PDF when there is no internet connection, it still fall back to export server. Can I know how do you export PDF without internet connection successfully?

Comment: Offline exporting module with disabled fallbackToExportServer works also for me now - http://jsfiddle.net/zzh1xd2b/2/

Comment: @morganfree, this also works for me, but the pie chart still not displaying. (I tested my code at Firefox browser locally.)

Comment: So I suggest reporting it on github [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues). There are some issues with the exporting offline pdf on IE10/11 reported there.